# Plot two y's against each other with the same confounders

Tags: generalized-linear-model, pca

So I was advised to use a GLM to adjust for confounding factors, but I have two variables I want to plot against each other and both are influenced by the same confounders. Can I use GLM for this, and if so how? If I use a GLM twice, once for each variable, can I combine them (how)? There are large numbers of covariates and I was going to reduce them with a PCA, but if I do will I still be able to combine the results of two GLMs (how)? [Sorry if this is Q is too complicated]

If content is useful: we're combining studies from different sites and want to control for climate, soils, etc, and plot yield against various environmental impacts, each impact has it's own dataset.
[it will be easy to lose me over 1st yr undergrad stats. Thanks!]

Comment: So it's been 8 days and no one has attempted to answer this or commented on it. Please could you also say if you know about statistics and you think this is a problematic thing to do. Or is there a better approach? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so maybe no one else cares, but we went to a stats clinic and this is what they said.

So we can do two GLMs for each of the variables we want to plot and plot them against each other, since they share the same covariates, so long as we only use that for visualisation and not for statistical inference. For the relationship we do a single GLM with the y-axis variable as the response variable and including the x-axis variable. PCA first to reduce dimensions is ok for non-explanatory variables we just want to model out. I'm sure you all knew that!